# Can you have too uniform test data in a feedforward neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, dataset, implementation

I have been playing around trying to implement my own feedforward neural network. To try it out I decided on an easy example. 3 inputs, 3 output. When you send in `(1,0,0)` the expected output is `(0,1,0)`. When you send in `(0,1,0)` the expected output is `(0,0,1)`. And so on, you see the pattern.

When working with a test data size of one I get a perfect result. After 100 training sessions with the input of `(1,0,0)` i get `(0.0192068, 0.980584, 0.0187576)` and the more I train the better the result is.

However when I try with 2 sets of training data `(1,0,0)` and `(0,1,0)`, I get the same result for trying both inputs after the training: `(0.0189567, 0.499995, 0.500002)` which isn't really what I wanted. The more I train the more even the result gets.

When I try with a 100 diffrent training examples (using an equal distribution of all 7 combinations: `(1, 0 ,0), (0, 1 ,0), (0, 0 ,1), (1, 1 ,0), (0, 1 ,1), (1, 0 ,1), (1, 1 ,1)`) the results get just more and more uniform : `(0.420004, 0.429997, 0.430002)`.

So my question is this: Could this result be in response to a general weakness of feedforward neural networks, in other words, it can't handle training data that is too uniform? Or do you think this could be because of a math error that has snuck in somewhere? I am afraid I am new enough to the concept of feedforward neural networks I can't tell one from the other.

Ps.: For those who are curious about what code I am using I am following this code:

https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network2.py

I am doing a port to C++ from that code example. I find porting code is a good way to learn because you really have to dig in deep into what every piece of the code is doing to get a clear understanding of how to port it. I also happen to be one of those weird ones that are more comfortable with C++ rather than Python DS.

Comment: That's the pythonic version, you are running C++ version? Looking at the outputs you shared, I guess(not sure at all) that network is not learning rather memorizing because for the network (100) or (001) or (010) will actually mean the same thing, Why I doubt this is because as you said, (111) also gives the same, so the network has successfully started detecting ones par-se

Comment: Yes this is me running own c++ version. I previus had unrelated problems with getting the same result for all values, but it turned out there was an error in the code making all the weigths between the input layer and the second layer 0 (meaning it went only by the biases) but that does not seem to be the case this time. Something i have noticed tho is that the more i train it the closer the smaller the first weights become (and who know maybe if i train long enough they will also become 0). Unsure if this is how it suppose to be or if that is normal for stocastic gradient decent.

Comment: If I am not wrong then 100,101 maps to 010; 010,011 maps to 001;110,111 maps to 011; in this case what's your goal actually? to detect the ones place?

Comment: So i want to teach the network to look at the 1s and then give an output where it shift all 1s to the right. In your example it would be 100 = 010,  101 = 110 and 111 = 111. Of course this is just an arbitrary example. I just wanted something simple where i could easily generate a lot of test data. Can you think of any other easy test you suggest i should try with ?

Comment: This is what I did when I began with nets .Try making the net map a linear or quadratic or polynomial equations ? In this case you k ow the original equation beforehand, just add noise to the actual values and watch the net to predict the correct equation's coefficients for you..or if you are comfortable enough, then throw in The MNIST dataset as a CSV format..Hope this helps.

Comment: Going for the MNIST dataset was going to my next step. I just figured i would try with something simpler first to try to isolate any error easier. could you perhaps give a few example inputs and outputs of your linear equation?

Comment: hava a line as y=8x+9 and get different y values for different x values..

Comment: If i say have (8x + 9, 0 ,0) as an input, how could i possible get a valid output say (y,0,0). The sigmoid compresses the value down between 0-1 ?

Comment: It's not like that, just pass in the coefficients of the polynomial equations

Comment: okay, so say we have 2x^2 + 3x -9 we would pass (2,3,-9) what would our expected output be ? I am sorry if I am asking stupid questions, I really like your suggestion it am just not quite following how to execute it :)

Comment: Suppose you have a eq `ax**2+bx+c`, our goal is to learn the coefficients of our polynomial function, so we will generate those values accordingly to our original values or nearby to them for faster convergence, the output in this case will have be a single node as will be calculating the offset as to how much our model differs in the actual polynomial values with original coefficients and the predicted one and then use backprop to train the network..Sorry but I guess you need to change your net a bit, adding another layer will improve the net or You can go for MNIST..

Comment: Here's mine version on MNIST (it's in Python)  https://github.com/AdityaSoni19031997/Machine-Learning/blob/master/Classifying_datasets/MNIST/neural_networks.py

Comment: The program is designed so you can dynamicly just input how many layers and how many nodes each should have. I implemented the MNIST testdata but it seems to be the same result, so i guess its back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Then something is wrong with the network's mathematics